# Stop li element outlines from touching

Tags: html, css

One of my assignments is to create a responsive webpage. I'm running into trouble when attempting to open it on mobiles. My 'li' elements touch and look awful.

How can I stop the 'box' around each li item from touching?

HTML -

```
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<body>
      <center>
         <div id="Menubar">
            <ul>
               <li id="active"><a href="Index.html">Home</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="Information.html">Services</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="Contact_us.html">Contact</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </center>
```

CSS -

```
      #Menubar ul {
     padding: .05em 0;
     margin: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
     background-color: #3A3734;
     color: #FFF;
     width: 100%;
     font-family: Oswald;
     font-size: 32pt;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     border-top:solid #8E7861 4px;
     border-bottom:solid #8E7861 4px;
 }
#Menubar ul li { display: inline; }
 li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 0 0 3px 0;
     background-color: white;
     color: #6AA0CC;
     padding: .1em 1em;
     border: 2px solid #6AA0CC;
 }
 li a:hover {
     background-color: #6AA0CC;
     color: #fff;
     border: 2px solid white;
 }
 .listcenter{
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8oxzorkt/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to the `li a` selector apart from other styles that you have applied.

```
li a {display:inline-block;}
```

Check the updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8oxzorkt/5/)

The important thing is that for responsive webpage you should use media queries as well.